# Storm - How to send data to REST services or Other user interface

Tags: rest, apache-storm

Is there any way that we can use to send the data to other application(s) by using Storm?

I am looking for options, in which we can send data to user interface or other REST service(s) through Apache Storm.

There are APIs available those we can use to send data to HDFS or other NoSQL database like Cassandra. However, I think we need to have an API which will send data to REST services running out side of Storm application.

Thanks in advance.

Avinash

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own REST call using any of HTTP library(apache http client for example) inside of bolt for sure, though there is no such in-built bolt.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply. I will try to implement the same.